# Linux mint | methods are missing from ncurses

Tags: linux-mint, compiling, c, c++, ncurses

I lately installed a linux mint distribution for development...
Later on i installed curses, ncurses and ncursesw by using following commands...

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev 
sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev 
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

Once i try to compile a program for university which uses ncurses ( Width )
it tells me following :

```
game.cpp: In member function ‘void game::run()’:
game.cpp:99:3: error: ‘mvaddwstr’ was not declared in this scope
mvaddwstr(player.pos.y, player.pos.x, player.disp_char);
^~~
game.cpp:99:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘mvaddstr’
mvaddwstr(player.pos.y, player.pos.x, player.disp_char);
^~~
mvaddstr
game.cpp:124:4: error: ‘addwstr’ was not declared in this scope
addwstr(player.disp_char);
^~~
game.cpp:124:4: note: suggested alternative: ‘addstr’
addwstr(player.disp_char);
^~~
```

Even when i Open a IDE to modify the includes, it tells me that those methods havent been found in the included .h file...

It works on my PopOS System, where i installed the same packages.

Any ideas why this may happen ?

Comment: Try adding a `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or `#define NCURSES_WIDECHAR 1` at the top of your program. It's hard to guess without a reproducible testcase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! That didnt worked sadly... Our project is too big to generate a test case :/

Comment: I don't believe that. Notice that you should put those defines _before_ including `curses.h`. Will this run without error? `cc -Wall -DNCURSES_WIDECHAR=1 -include curses.h -lncursesw -xc - <<<'int main(void){ mvaddwstr(0,0,0); }'`

Comment: Thanks, yes we defined those before the include :) The result of the cc tells us "undefined reference to mvaddwstr"... this doesnt make sense at all...

Comment: It's the `cc` command from my testcase which fails with `undefined reference to mvaddwstr`? or the `cc` command you're using to compile your project?